# Passing received value from onClick events across different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

Let's say we got two different React components. One contains reports with dates, the other should show employees that worked that particular month.

So depending on what reports month was clicked, I need to be able to show those employees, but in a second component.

I'm able to get the date that was clicked in the first one but in order to know which employees to show I need to compare that data (from the 1st component) with employees data (second component).

The big question here is - HOW CAN I TRANSFER THAT NEWLY CONSTRUCTED (onClick - Custom function)EVENTS DATA TO THAT SECOND COMPONENT SO I CAN COMPARE THEM ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "Parent" component which will render your two components.

The Parent component will have the selected date in the state.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.handleDateChange = this.handleDateChange.bind(this);
    this.state = { date: null };
  }

  handleDataChange(date) {
    this.setState({ date });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Component1 onDateChange={this.handeDataChange} />
        <Component2 date={this.state.date} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You have to update your `Component1` to receive `onDateChange`, and you have to call that function when the date is updated:

```
// where the date is updated
this.props.onDateChange(newDate);
```

Also you have to update your `Component2` to receive `date` (the selected date) which you can use to filter your employees:

```
// maybe in the render function... you will know the selected date with this.props.date. For example you could do something like this:
const filtered = this.employees.filter(employee => employee.date === this.props.date);
```

**How does this work?**

- when you select your date in your first component, it will call `handleDateChange`
- ... It will update Parent's state
- ... then Parent's render function will be called (because the state changed)
- ... then it will pass the new date (stored in the state) to the second component.

Answer (score 0):

Contain the component within a common parent component that's then able to act as a broker for the relevant data.

> Often, several components need to reflect the same changing data. We recommend lifting the shared state up to their closest common ancestor. 
>   [From: [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)]

This is simplified but something like:

```
class Employees extends Component {
  state = {
    employees: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { clickedDate } = this.props
    const employees = await fetchEmployees(clickedDate) // or whatever
    this.setState({ employees })
  }

  render() {
    const { employees } = this.state

    if (employees.length === 0) {
      return
        <p>Loading...</p>
    }

    return (
      <div className='employees'>
        {
          employees.map(employee => (
            <p>{employee}</p>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Reports = ({ dates, setClickedDate }) => (
  <div className='reports'>
    {
      dates.map(date => (
        <p onClick={() => setClickedDate(date)}>{date}</p>
      ))
    }
  </div>
)

class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    clickedDate: undefined,
    dates: ['dates', 'from', 'somewhere']
  }

  setClickedDate = clickedDate => this.setState({ clickedDate })

  render() {
    const { clickedDate } = this.state

    return [
      <Reports dates={dates} setClickedDate={this.setClickedDate} />,
      <Employees clickedDate={clickedDate} />
    ]
  }
}
```